# Can secretary of a faculty upload letter of recommendation on behalf of the letter author?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, professorship, recommendation-letter

I am applying for Ph.D. positions in the USA and for that I have asked the department head of my past institute to write a LOR for me. He agreed to write one for me but the problem is I am applying to multiple universities (6-8). The professor is very busy which seems too much to ask for uploading LORs for multiple schools.
I want to know if it's ok if his secretary can upload the LOR on his behalf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's part of a faculty job to handle letters of recommendation. Do not worry about being a bother -- they are used to handling these requests. If this person has previously told you to contact their secretary, then contact the secretary. If not, then send your request to him, and let him decide how to handle it. He may decide the way to handle it is to ask you to forward subsequent requests to the secretary -- that is normal and fine.

Having said that, there are ways to be helpful -- create an organized spreadsheet or table with all of the links for places to upload the letters. If you find new positions to apply for after you first send the table, batch updates together so you send one updated link to the spreadsheet with a new set (instead of lots of "one-off" emails).